Move or copy data from one column into another column
All I want to do is grab all the data in column "Name 2" and "Lastname 2" and move it under the data in column "Name 1" and "Lastname 1" respectively, and bring the ID along with it, e.g. like so,
Example:



Name1
Lastname 1
Name 2
Lastname 2
ID




John
Smith
Jessica
Jackman
1


Mario
Rossi
Pietro
Biondi
2






Name1
Lastname 1
ID




John
Smith
1


Mario
Rossi
2


Jessica
Jackman
1


Pietro
Biondi
2



Here is the code I have thus far which firstly cleans up the duplicate column names and names them 1 and 2. It then concatenates the Name1 and Name2 columns and concatenates Lastname1 and Lastname2 columns.
What I don't understand is that when I assign the concatenated column to a variable and I print that variable, I will see the entire list as I want it, but once I assign it to a new column, it does not.
I have 12 objects (rows), once I concatenated I should have 25. When I do the print(com_name) it outputs 25 objects. Nice!
Then I assign it to a new column, export as a CSV and the new column is there, but only with 12 objects. I am confused as to what is happening.
import os
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('Arraytomodify.csv', sep=",", na_values='?')

data.rename(columns={"Nome / Name": "Name1"}, inplace=True)

data.rename(columns={"Nome / Name.1": "Name2"}, inplace=True)

data.rename(columns={"Cognome / Nachname": "Lastname1"}, inplace=True)

data.rename(columns={"Cognome / Nachname.1": "Lastname2"}, inplace=True)

com_name = pd.concat([data['Name1'], data['Name2']], ignore_index=True)

com_last = pd.concat([data['Lastname1'], data['Lastname2']], ignore_index=True)

print(com_name)
print(com_last)

data['com_name'] = com_nome

data['com_last'] = com_last

print(data['com_name'])

screenshot
If you take a look at the screenshot, you'll see 25 objects on the first print. But once I assign the concatenated variable to a column and then print it, you'll see I am left with a list of 12.
